# How can I get rid of one of the default gateways?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ip, gateway

I have two default gateways on my virtual machine.

```
Default Gateway: 
172.31.144.1
172.25.16.1
```

Is there a way to get rid of one?

[image: screenshot of interface details]

Comment: Do you two network cards, each connected to a different router?

Comment: Your VM appears to be connected by NAT with an internal DHCP server.  Is that what you are looking at?

Comment: Nope @harrymc the vm uses the hosts's physical nic that is connected to only one router

Comment: @John yes but before before there was only one default gateway 172.25.16.1 and now there is another one which i cant seem to figure out where it had come from

Comment: I amended my answer to include TCP/IP Reset.  Do that on each guest to clean up TCP/IP

Answer (score 0):

I have a Default Gateway for my host machine (Router): 192.168.nnn.1

and a different Default Gateway in my Windows 10 VM originating from the fact that the Windows 10 VM uses NAT and the VM app (VMware in my case) provides an Internal DHCP Server.  192.168.233.2

233 is the internal subnet with its own DHCP server and Gateway.

If you tried both Bridged and NAT connections, Bridged will give you 1 Gateway and NAT will give you 2 Gateways.

So nothing is wrong; situation normal.

You might wish to do a TCP/IP Reset on the Virtual Machines to clear out old information.

```
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
```

Use the equivalent Linux commands for a Linux guest.

Comment: But for my other Window's 10 Virtual Machine it only shows one default gateway?

Comment: It depends on the network connection whether 1 or 2 and can vary by machine. Perhaps do a TCP/IP Reset on your VMs to clear out old stuff.